# Loop only outputting last iteration of data in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm running a loop in R, where I want to take some information about different Speakers from one dataframe and combine it with information in another dataframe. When I run a test using one speaker, the code runs fine, but when I run the loop the output gives me only the final speaker in the data.

```
 # Create sample dataframes
 library(tibble)

 df1 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age,
           "A", 10,
           "B", 14,
           "C", 44,
           "D", 22)

 df2 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age,
           "A", 10,
           "A", 11,
           "A", 12,
           "B", 13,
           "B", 14,
           "B", 15,
           "C", 45,
           "C", 46,
           "C", 47,
           "D", 22,
           "D", 23,
           "D", 24)

 # create empty dataframes for outputted data
 output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
 col_names <- c("Speaker", "age", "group")
 colnames(output) <- col_names 

 for (i in df1$Speaker) {
  data_age <- df2 %>%
  filter(Speaker == i) %>%
  filter(Speaker == df1$Speaker & age >= df1$age) %>%    # take data from or after age in df1
  mutate(group = "group1") %>%
  select(Speaker, age, group)
  output <- data_age
  }
```

My expected output should look like:

```
 output <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age, ~group,
           "A", 10, "group1",
           "A", 11, "group1",
           "A", 12, "group1",
           "B", 13, NA,
           "B", 14, "group1",
           "B", 15, "group1",
           "C", 45, "group1",
           "C", 46, "group1",
           "C", 47, "group1",
           "D", 22, "group1",
           "D", 23, "group1",
           "D", 24, "group1")
```

From what I can find in other posts, this seemed to be something to do with the first line of the loop, where I don't have `i in 1:length()`, or perhaps the output file that I am trying to create, which is being overwritten (as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738534/r-loop-outputting-only-the-last-iteration)). When I change the code in line with either of these suggestions, I end up with a blank data frame.

Comment: Can you please share your expected result? It seems there is an issue with your filter statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues. First your `filter()` needed adjusting. You don't need to filter for both `Speaker == i` and `Speaker == df1$Speaker` since `i` is defined as an element from `df1$speaker`. Second, you need to provide a specific value of `df1$age` that matches `i`. Finally, each run of the loop overwrites `output` rather than something like `rbind()` to add rows to `output`.

```
for (i in df1$Speaker) {
  data_age <- df2 %>%
    filter(Speaker == i) %>%
    filter(age >= df1$age[which(df1$Speaker == i)]) %>%    # take data from or after age in df1
    mutate(group = "group1") %>%
    select(Speaker, age, group)
  output <- rbind(output, data_age)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the initial question has already been answered, I'd like to provide you with an alternative approach.

To combine data.frames usually you should use joins over for-loops, as they are much faster.

Here is a [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)-way to get to the same output:

```
library(tibble)
library(data.table)

df1 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age,
               "A", 10,
               "B", 14,
               "C", 44,
               "D", 22)

df2 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age,
               "A", 10,
               "A", 11,
               "A", 12,
               "B", 13,
               "B", 14,
               "B", 15,
               "C", 45,
               "C", 46,
               "C", 47,
               "D", 22,
               "D", 23,
               "D", 24)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

output <- df2[df1, on = "Speaker"][age >= i.age, group := "group1"][,i.age := NULL]
```

---

```
> output
    Speaker age  group
 1:       A  10 group1
 2:       A  11 group1
 3:       A  12 group1
 4:       B  13   <NA>
 5:       B  14 group1
 6:       B  15 group1
 7:       C  45 group1
 8:       C  46 group1
 9:       C  47 group1
10:       D  22 group1
11:       D  23 group1
12:       D  24 group1
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done without loops:

```
output <- df2 %>%
    left_join(
        df1 %>% rename(age_min = age)
        ,by="Speaker"
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        group = if_else(age >= age_min, "group1", NA_character_)
    ) %>%
    select(Speaker, age, group)
```